# find frequency of a int appear in a list of interval

Tags: python, optimization, time-complexity

I were given a list of intervals, for example [[10,40],[20,60]] and a list of position [5,15,30]
we should return the frequency of position appeared in the list, the answer would be [[5,0],[15,1],[30,2]] because 5 didn't cover by the interval and 15 was covered once, 30 was covered twice.
If I just do a for loop the time complexity would be O(m*n) m is the number of the interval, n is the number of position
Can I preprocess the intervals and make it faster? I was thinking of sort the interval first and use binary search but I am not sure how to implement it in python, Can someone give me a hint? Or can I use a hashtable to store intervals? what would be the time complexity for that?

Comment: Seems like you could build a data structure that's stored as a sequence of non-overlapping ranges associated with frequencies.  Use binary search to locate the range for a given "position" or to integrate a new range into the structure, and that should make both operations log(m), so you'd end up with (m+n)log(m) to build the structure out of the intervals and then query the list of positions.

Comment: hm not quite mlog(m) to build it, since you need to iterate over the overlapping ranges to integrate them, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a frequency array to preprocess all interval data and then query for any value to get the answer. Specifically, create an array able to hold the min and max possible end-points of all the intervals. Then, for each interval, increment the frequency of the starting interval point and decrease the frequency of the value just after the end interval. At the end, accumulate this data for the array and we will have the frequency of occurrence of each value between the min and max of the interval. Each query is then just returning the frequency value from this array.

1. freq[] --> larger than max-min+1 (min: minimum start value, max: maximum end value)
2. For each [L,R] --> freq[L]++, freq[R+1] = freq[R+1]-1
3. freq[i] = freq[i]+freq[i-1]
4. For any query V, answer is freq[V]

Do consider tradeoffs when range is very large compared to simple queries, where simple check for all may suffice.